# match common lines in 2 files and edit the second file in regex

Tags: regex

I am stuck on the last step and hope someone could help me out.

I have 2 files:

file1 =

> Green Apple

file2 =

> Green Apple/quantity/100
>
> Red Peach/quantity/200

My code:

> grep -f file1 file2 | sed 's/quantity(.*)/totalXYZ/'
>
> = Green Apple/totalXYZ

I would like to apply it to file2 so the result would look like this:

file2 =

> Green Apple/totalXYZ
>
> Red Peach/quantity/200

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using AWK this way:

```
awk -f grepandreplace.awk file2 file1
```

The code of "grepandreplace.awk" is:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = "/";
    f_grep = ARGV[2];
    ARGC = 2;

    while ((getline < f_grep) > 0) {
        grep[$1] = "";
    }
}

{
    if ($1 in grep) {
        print $1"/totalXYZ";
    } else {
        print $0;
    }
}
```

And I got your desired output:

```
Green Apple/totalXYZ
Red Peach/quantity/200
```

Any questions? leave me a comment.

Comment: I also found another way to do it in one line (see my next answer). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in one line using 2 greps: the first one for matching and the second one using the invert-matching (-v).
And then append the second output to the first one:

```
echo -e `grep -f file1 file2 | sed 's/quantity.*/totalXYZ/'`"\n"`grep -vf file1 file2`
```

Comment: Thanks again rmunoz.  Yes, this also worked!  But how do I make it write to file2?  I had in mind:  sed -i ....

Comment: Actually, using your code, I will redirect it to file3, then mv file3 file2.  Thanks again rmunoz for the help.

Comment: You do not need file3, you can redirect the output to file2. You are welcome ;-)